# In a python script how can I ignore Apache Pig's Python Decorators for standalone unit testing

Tags: python, testing, decorator, apache-pig

I have a python script which is executed in Jython under Apache Pig. It defines some functions with the `@schemaFunction` resp. the  `@outputSchemaFunction` decorator.

I want to test theses function with a standalone python main script outside Pig just under a "normal local Python interpreter. However when I run the script under a local Python system, the interpreter complains: `"NameError: name 'outputSchema' is not defined"` I understand that the standalone Python obviously does not support these decorators.

How can I test my script in a local Python interpreter? Can I somehow define the decorators in the calling script as "empty"? Or is there something like a command line option to ignore decorators?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using pig 0.10.0.

When the module is used by pig as a UDF it sets `__name__` to `__lib__`.  Normally, `__name__` is set to the actual name of the module (minus the .py).  Therefore, you can define some empty decorators for `outputSchema` and `outputSchemaFunction` inside of an if block.  Something like:

**myudfs.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

if __name__ != '__lib__':
    def outputSchema(dont_care):
        def wrapper(func):
            def inner(*args, **kwargs):
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            return inner
        return wrapper

# Your UDFs go here
```

You can verify this yourself by putting `print __name__` at the top of the `myudfs.py`.

Comment: Works perfectly. I'm using pig 0.11.1. Thanks.